# Google analytics: how to count occurrences of each item in internal search listing

Tags: google-analytics

In company I am working on a website that presents users' announcements. Announcements can be searched through our internal search engine. SO far we have implemented Googla Analytics API to present our users 'pageViews' information of their announcement, but they also want to know how often their announcement has been shown in search listing (probably to compare with pageviews and later modify some information like title or thumbnail of announcement to gain CTR). How can we collect such data? I obviously tried to google it, but couldn't find any information.